# How to calculate derivative of $\int_0 ^{x^2} f(t^2)\,dt $

Tags: calculus, integration

Could anyone give me a quick reminder on how to compute the derivative of integrals of this form? If I see one, I will know how to solve all others. Forgot the difference with $f(t^2)$ in comparison to $f(t)$.

> $$\int_0 ^{x^2} f(t^2)\,dt  $$

Thanks in advance to who can give me a reminder!

Comment: That can't be done in general, but you should look at what happens when we substitute $u=t^{1/2}$ or $u=t^2$.

Comment: Alright but then du = 2tdt for instance and how would I implement that then?

Comment: What exactly do you want to solve here?

Comment: Sorry I am stupid, I meant the derivative of this of course, I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find $\displaystyle \frac {d}{dx}\int^{x^2}_0 f(t^2)dt$.

$\displaystyle \frac {d}{dx}\int^{x^2}_0 f(t^2)dt = \frac{d(x^2)}{dx}\frac{d}{d(x^2)}\int^{x^2}_0 f(t^2)dt = 2xf(x^4)$, where you employed the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: There's a slight error in your result; can you see it?

Comment: @J.G. Sorry, I meant power $4$, that was a typo. Appreciate you catching it, I was just on the way to editing it.

Comment: thanks to you both, remember everything now! :)

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule,$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^2}f(t^2)dt=\frac{dx^2}{dx}\frac{d}{dx^2}\int_0^{x^2}f(t^2)dt=2xf((x^2)^2)=2xf(x^4).$$

Comment: thanks both for your help!